# Nmon analyzer automation issue

Tags: linux, excel, vba

I have NMON installed on my Linux servers and I collect all the nmon files and save it an folder, later I use a NMON analyzer to generate reports.

When I am doing it manually I am facing no issue, but when I am providing the nmon analyzer a file of list of nmon files(FilesList) [nmon setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qrCv.png) to be processed it giving me an pop up [pop up message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYLNa.png).

After I click to yes to all pops then it generates the reports. As I have scripted all of these the program is waiting  for the response. Is there any to stop this popup.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/nmon/support-requests/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all little clarifications:
nmon and the nmon Analyser are not to be mixed up

**Nmon:**

> nmon is a C program and is a Sourceforce project - the
>   current version is 16d.

**Nmon Analyser:**

> The nmon Analyser is a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet and the current
>   version is 4.7 with a new release curently in testing and is maintained by IBM

This clarifications is required as the issue can be from any of the above two  projects and hence should differently addressed. This issue is related to the later one i.e Nmon Analyser

**Reason:**
Basically my data had multiple AAA,x86, records which was causing the error within the PP_AAA Create.Labels function but only if MERGE = NO.

**Fix:**
the PP_AAA Create.Labels function should have  MERGE = YES.

Fixed Nmon Analyzer file --> [NmonAnalyser.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7YnPsHwbHY8R0tFa0phV2hkZW8)

Thanks to Nigel Griffiths from SourceForge and Ron McCargar from IBM for their time and effort.